# Populate JavaScript array in middle of each value

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am attempting to populate array:

```
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

With some random number/value, so that the value separates each original value.
However, using a for loop like this:

```
for (var am = 1; am < array2.length; am+2) {
   array2.splice(am, 0, undefined);
}
```

Causes my browser to freeze, since on each splice the array2's length mutates and causes an infinite loop so I attempted this method:

```
var l = array2.length;

for(var i = 1; i < l; i+2) {
   array2.splice(i, 0, undefined);
}
```

Now I don't know what's going on. I assume `l` is mutating again.

I have to advance `i` for two because array2 after the first splice becomes:

```
["a", undefined, "b", "c"];
```

However, since `i = 3` and I've set the expression `i < l`, the only explanation is that `l` is changing again.

Any explanation would be welcome. The end result of how I want the code to proceed is:

```
array2 = ["a", undefined, "b", undefined, "c"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var am = 1; am < array2.length; am+2) {
```

You're not actually incrementing `am` in that line. Change it to:

```
for (var am = 1; am < array2.length; am+=2) {
```

Using `+=` means `am = am + 2`

Comment: Oops, I probably never used anything else than `am++` so I forgot about that one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c"];

var l = array2.length;

// Stop 1 item before the end and set steps of 1 item
for(var i = 0; i < (l - 1); ++i) {
   // You inserting starting from index 1 and move 2 items ahead for each element
   array2.splice(1 + (i * 2), 0, undefined);
}
```

Comment: Or just `while(--l>0){array2.splice(l,0,undefined);}`

Comment: yea, that's actually a much nicer notation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c"],
    length = array2.length,
    output = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
  output.push(array2[i]);
  if ( i < length - 1 ) {
    output.push(undefined);
  }
}

// output:
// ["a", undefined, "b", undefined, "c"]
```